# CMake, shared library linking fail

Tags: cmake, shared-libraries, dynamic-linking

I'm currently getting used to cmake and I'm trying to compile a small project with a .so library linking.

My project is the following.

```
/
   CMakeLists.txt
   inc/
       Als.h
   src/
       main.c
       CMakeLists.txt
   lib/
       libals.so
   build/
```

I'm compiling from the build directory with:

```
$ cmake ..
-- DIR: 
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/julien/tmp/cmakeTest/build
```

And then:

```
$ make
Linking C executable cmakeTest
/usr/bin/ld: ne peut trouver -lals
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
src/CMakeFiles/cmakeTest.dir/build.make:85: recipe for target 'src/cmakeTest' failed
make[2]: *** [src/cmakeTest] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:75: recipe for target 'src/CMakeFiles/cmakeTest.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/cmakeTest.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:76: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

The linker seems to be unable to find the libals.so file.

Here is the file /CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

PROJECT(cmaketest)

set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -Wall")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -Werror")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -O3")

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(
  inc
)

ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(src)

get_directory_property(OUT_VAR LINK_DIRECTORIES)
message(STATUS "DIR: ${OUT_VAR}")
```

And here is the file /src/CMakeLists.txt:

```
PROJECT(cmakeTest)

FILE(
    GLOB
    ${PROJECT_NAME}_Sources
    *.c
)

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(
        inc
        inc
)

ADD_EXECUTABLE(
    ${PROJECT_NAME}
    ${${PROJECT_NAME}_Sources}
)

LINK_DIRECTORIES(
    /home/julien/tmp/cmakeTest/lib/
)

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(
    ${PROJECT_NAME}
    als
    pthread
)
```

Maybe I missed something but if I change the /src/CMakeLists.txt to:

```
PROJECT(cmakeTest)

FILE(
    GLOB
    ${PROJECT_NAME}_Sources
    *.c
)

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(
        inc
        inc
)

ADD_EXECUTABLE(
    ${PROJECT_NAME}
    ${${PROJECT_NAME}_Sources}
)

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(
    ${PROJECT_NAME}
    /home/julien/tmp/cmakeTest/lib/libals.so
    pthread
)
```

The compilation is ok. Does someone know why the linker is unable to find libals.so when I'm giving him the good directory path to look in?

The LINK_DIRECTORIES functions seems not to be working.

Comment: "The compilation is ok" - So don't add the C and "compilation" tags.

Comment: My suggestion is that you [add the library as an imported target](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.8/command/add_library#imported-libraries), set its location property ([see example here](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake/Tutorials/Exporting_and_Importing_Targets)) and simply use it as a normal library (like you use the `pthread` library in your project). Effectively it's not really different than your working `CMakeLists.txt` IMO it's more "cmake-ish".

Comment: Also, you should probably run `make` with `VERBOSE=1` to see the commands that `cmake` has generated to build your target. Then you can see what flags and options it passes to the linker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides the solution you already have, and my solution in a comment, the problem you have with the CMake file shown is the order in which you invoke the CMake commands.

[From the `link_directories` command reference](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.8/command/link_directories.html):

> The command will apply only to targets created **after it is called**.

<sub>[Emphasis mine]</sub>

You simply need to call `link_directories` *before* you call `add_executable`.

Comment: That was the problem. Thanks a lot ;)